# How to create & publish an mobile app combining multiple power bi reports?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-mobile

Pardon my ignorance on this question and I am quite new to Power BI. I am using Power BI Services and created a dashboard combining pages from three seperate power bi reports. Now I want to publish this dashboard as an mobile app or atleast a link on the mobile. If I use a power bi mobile native app, it just allows me to call individual dashboards that means user got to log in and launch dashboards. The expectation is just launch the app showing the dashboard directly and like this I should be able to publish multiple icons on the mobile launching seperate dashboards. Any insight on this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can write an app and embed this dashboard in it. Here are the official [samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples) (you will probably prefer to implement `App Owns Data` scenario). A good place to start is [Embedded analytics with Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedding). Take a look at [Power BI Embedded's wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki) too. [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-For-Mobile) is how you can embed the mobile view.

In essence, embedding Power BI elements is loading them in an empty `<div>` in a web page shown in a browser. The heavy lifting is done by [Power BI javascript client](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript). You need to authenticate against the API (`User Owns Data` means each user uses his own Power BI account, `App Owns Data` means you use one master account for all users), acquire an access token (use [ADAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) for that), and use this access token later to call the [Power BI REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/).

Comment: Hi Andrey, You mentioned "app", I assume it's a web app, Is that right?

Comment: It can be, but it can also be a desktop app. It's web technology so using it in a web app could be easier, but it's possible to embed it in native desktop app too.